# How to put where condition on nested relation in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I have table Invoice which has relation with `consignment` `hasMany`

```
public function consignments_invoices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\Consignment', 'invoice_id');
}
```

and consignment has relation `hasMany` with `Charge`

```
public function charges()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\Charge', 'object_id')->where('model', 'Consignment');
}
```

Here in `charge` I want to put where clause on attribute `rate_zone_id`

How i can achieve this?

I have existing query like

```
Invoice
    ::when(!empty($request->customer_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
        return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
    })
    ->where('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)
    ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date)
    ->with('consignments_invoices')->
    ->when(!empty($request->rate_zone_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
        //Here is want to use where condition on rate zone id
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). `whereHas()` can take a nested relationships using dot notation (`consignments_invoices.charges`) so you would have something like:

```
$query->whereHas('consignments_invoices.charges', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('rate_zone_id', $request->rate_zone_id);
});
```

---

Furthermore, [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) passes the first parameter as the second argument to the callback so you could have something like:

```
->when($request->rate_zone_id, function ($q, $rateZoneId) {
    $q->whereHas('consignments_invoices.charges', function ($q) use ($rateZoneId) {
        $q->where('rate_zone_id', $rateZoneId);
    });
})
```

This would mean the entire query would look something like:

```
Invoice
    ::when($request->customer_id, function ($q, $customerId)  {
        return $q->where('customer_id', $customerId);
    })
    ->when($request->rate_zone_id, function ($q, $rateZoneId) {
        $q->whereHas('consignments_invoices.charges', function ($q) use ($rateZoneId) {
            $q->where('rate_zone_id', $rateZoneId);
        });
    })
    ->where('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)
    ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date)
    ->get();
```

---

The above will limit the Invoices to the specific `rate_zone_id` (when it's supplied), however, it won't constrain the `consignments_invoices`.

For this, you will need to constrain the `consignments_invoices` relationship in the `with()` call as well:

```
->with([
    'consignments_invoices' => function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->with('charges')->when($request->rate_zone_id, function ($q, $rateZoneId) {
            $q->whereHas('charges', function ($q) use ($rateZoneId) {
                $q->where('rate_zone_id', $rateZoneId);
            });
        });
    },
])
```

This will mean your entire query will look like:

```
Invoice
    ::with([
        'consignments_invoices' => function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->with('charges')->when($request->rate_zone_id, function ($q, $rateZoneId) {
                $q->whereHas('charges', function ($q) use ($rateZoneId) {
                    $q->where('rate_zone_id', $rateZoneId);
                });
            });
        },
    ])
    ->when($request->customer_id, function ($q, $customerId)  {
        return $q->where('customer_id', $customerId);
    })
    ->when($request->rate_zone_id, function ($q, $rateZoneId) {
        $q->whereHas('consignments_invoices.charges', function ($q) use ($rateZoneId) {
            $q->where('rate_zone_id', $rateZoneId);
        });
    })
    ->where('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)
    ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date)
    ->get()
```

Comment: its working but it is also  fetching those consignments which are not having rate_zone_id

Comment: if one consignment's charge having correct rate_zone_id it is fetching all of its consignments

Comment: @BilalArshad Where/how are you loading the consignments? I didn't see that in your original question.

Comment: @BilalArshad Are you also going to be loading the charges as well?

Comment: @BilalArshad Did this answer you question? If so, please may you mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested relationship

```
 Invoice::when(!empty($request->customer_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
        return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
    })->where('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date)
        ->when(!empty($request->rate_zone_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereHas('consignments_invoices.charges',function ($query) use ($request){
                $query->where('rate_zone_id',$request->rate_zone_id);
            });
        })->get();
```

Comment: if one consignment's charge having correct rate_zone_id it is fetching all of its consignme

Comment: Invoice::when(!empty($request->customer_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
        return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
    })->where('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date)
        ->whereHas('consignments_invoices')
        ->when(!empty($request->rate_zone_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereHas('consignments_invoices.charges',function ($query) use ($request){
                $query->where('rate_zone_id',$request->rate_zone_id);
            });
        })->get();

Answer (score 0):

```
$invoice = Invoice::with('charges')
            ->when(!empty($request->customer_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
                return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
            })
            ->whereDate('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)
            ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date);
    if (!empty($request->rate_zone_id)) {
        $invoice->whereHas('charges', function ($query1)use($request) {
            $query1->where('rate_zone_id', $request->rate_zone_id);
        });
    }
    $invoices = $invoice->get()->toArray();
```

Or

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('charges')
                    ->when(!empty($request->customer_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
                        return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
                    })
                    ->whereDate('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)
                    ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date)
                    ->when(!empty($request->rate_zone_id), function ($query1) use ($request) {
                        $rate_zone_id = $request->rate_zone_id;
                        $query1->whereHas('charges', function ($query2)use($rate_zone_id) {
                            $query2->where('rate_zone_id', $rate_zone_id );
                        });
                    })->get()->toArray();



$invoice = Invoice::when(!empty($request->customer_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
                return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
            })
            ->whereDate('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)
            ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date);
    if (!empty($request->rate_zone_id)) {
        $rate_zone_id = $request->rate_zone_id;
        $invoice->with(['charges', function ($query1)use($rate_zone_id) {
                $query1->where('rate_zone_id', $rate_zone_id);
            }]);
    }
    $invoices = $invoice->get()->toArray();
```

use whereHas=> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: if one consignment's charge having correct rate_zone_id it is fetching all of its consignme

Comment: okay then in this case also add condition with eager loading

Comment: $invoice = Invoice::when(!empty($request->customer_id), function ($q) use ($request) {
                    return $q->where('customer_id', $request->customer_id);
                })
                ->whereDate('start_date', '>=', $request->start_date)
                ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $request->end_date);
        if (!empty($request->rate_zone_id)) {
            $invoice->with('charges', function ($query1)use($request) {
                $query1->where('rate_zone_id', $request->rate_zone_id);
            });
        }
        $invoices = $invoice->get()->toArray();

Comment: Still same results

Comment: rate_zone_id single or multiple?

Comment: rate_zone_id is single

Comment: getting this error `message: "mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"`

Comment: same result i think you are missing `consignments_invoices` relation

Comment: in this consignments_invoices  with charges relationship?

Comment: actually solution working fine i just want to get those consignment invoices in which charges having specific rate zone id

Comment: if you have consignments_invoices with charges then you need with inside with condition

Comment: can you please give example

Comment: you got it data ?